# ViewPager with TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-viewpager

I have this application that is visible in the Gallery build in Android application. When I selected multiple images and press via "Share Application", the application I'm developing, the application starts and all the images selected are displayed in `ViewPager` to swipe between them.

On each page, I have an `ImageView`, TextView`and`EditText`. The`ImageView`to display the image. The`TextView`to set the date (using date picker) and`EditText` to set the title.

The problem is when i set the date or title on a certain and swipe to the next then re-swipe back the information i set is erased.

I want the information to be saved not wiped or edited due to a change on the next pages.

How can I do that?
I have the codes if anyone would like to see.

Comment: If your pages in viewpager are limited use the FragmentPagerAdapter for your viewpager. The FragmentPagerAdapter will cached the fragments in memory and state its state for you.

Comment: what do you mean my limited?

Comment: Around 10-20 images/text/dates.